# Update if exists, else insert new record, all based on checkboxes

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I'm having some issues using checkboxes in combination with an insert/update statement. As it stands, I have a report of available credit cards, with a checkbox next to each row. The user can select as many as they like to approve, then hit a submit button to have their profile updated. This is where I am stuck.

I would like to have a single PSQL process that will update the user profile table based on whether or not said credit card is there. If it doesn't exist, then we insert all relevant information. If it already is there, all I want to do is update that record by changing 'Approved_flag' to 'Y'. I've written this code chunk, which inserts new records and it works fine:

```
FOR i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.count
 LOOP
  INSERT INTO ls_credit_cards(credit_card_id, created_by, created_on, card_id,    user_id, approved_flag)
  VALUES (apex_application.g_f01(i), :F125_USER_ID,sysdate, :P58_CARDS, :P58_USER, 'Y');
 END LOOP;
```

I understand that ORACLE doesn't support the usual if/else commands, so I've researched this a bit and found that I should probably be using the MERGE command, but everything I've seen makes it use two tables. All I'm using is one, with all data being taken from the report/check boxes so I'm kind of at a loss here. Can I still use the MERGE command in this instance, or is there something else that would serve my purposes better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MERGE`.  You just need to select your data from `DUAL'

```
MERGE INTO ls_credit_cards dest
  USING( SELECT apex_application.g_f01(i) credit_card_id, 
                :F125_USER_ID created_by,
                sysdate created_on, 
                :P58_CARDS card_id, 
                :P58_USER user_id, 
                'Y' approved_flag
           FROM dual) src
      ON( dest.credit_card_id = src.credit_card_id )
 WHEN MATCHED 
 THEN
   UPDATE SET dest.approved_flag = src.approved_flag
 WHEN NOT MATCHED
 THEN
   INSERT( credit_card_id, 
           created_by,
           created_on,
           card_id,
           user_id,
           approved_flag )
     VALUES( src.credit_card_id,
             src.created_by,
             src.created_on,
             src.card_id,
             src.user_id,
             src.approved_flag );
```

Comment: I hate to be an annoyance, but this isn't quite working 100% for me. It works fine for updating existing data, but it still doesn't insert new data for some reason. There are no error messages, so I'm again at a loss as to why it would put in new records.

Comment: @user1200142 - Are you sure there are new rows to insert?  Or, perhaps my guess as to what columns to match on is incorrect and you need to match on more than just the `CREDIT_CARD_ID` column.  Perhaps you need to match on some of the other `ID` columns as well?

Comment: Issue was my own creation. I had improperly assigned credit card id's to cards that were to be inserted as new. If I hard code an ID, it works perfectly. That just means I'll have to do a bit of creative problem solving! Thanks very much though, this is perfect!